# SPARQL query: no return

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, geonames

Why does this SPARQL query return a result:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
?c <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#name> ?a .}
LIMIT 20
```

result:

[image]

While this returns an empty table of columns a and b:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
?c <http://dbpedia.org/ontology#name> ?a .}
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: DBpedia uses slashes (`/`), [not](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HashVsSlash) hashes (`#`) in URIs. Also, what the data you are querying against? Are you still using SILK Framework? Then provide some example data.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! that solved the problem :))

Comment: Please add a short answer for the steps you took to solve this problem yourself and mark the question resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the # in dbpedia's by / as in follows:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
?c <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/name> ?a .}
LIMIT 20
```

This means any prefixes for dbpedia should include / instead of # as well. :)